# Optimize the query without using not in clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
          Hi i want to write the below query in different way can you please
```

tell me how  can i write in different way.So it will take minimum time 
  to execute. without using index.I written the query is getting exact output but it takes too much time

```
select distinct location from get_shipping_data gsd
where  location  not in

(
select pkd.shipmentlocation from package p
left join packagedetail pkd on pkd.packingid=p.packingid
where p.shippingnum='SH0667075'

)
and gsd.shipmentid='SH0667075'
```

Comment: It would be much more useful if you pasted the *text* of your query and desired output, instead of an image. Secondly, if the query is working, you should probably post on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: are you using should return two results in 1 row? the use STUFF

Answer (score 0):

There's not much besides suggestions here, without indexes you can write your query using join:

```
select distinct location 
  from get_shipping_data gsd
       inner join 
       (select p.shippingnum, pkd.shipmentlocation 
          from package p
                left join packagedetail pkd 
                on pkd.packingid=p.packingid
         where p.shippingnum='SH0667075') ps
        ON gsd.location = ps.shipmentlocation
           AND gsd.shipmentid = ps.shippingnum
where ps.shipmentlocation is null
  AND gsd.shipmentid='SH0667075'
```

Try it and see if it gives you any improvement.

Comment: How so? can you explain?